# Why do inode numbers start from 1 and not 0?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, inode, superblock

The C language convention counts array indices from 0. Why do inode numbers start from 1 and not 0?

If inode 0 is reserved is for some special use, then what is the significance of inode 0?

Comment: Do you have a reference to back up the claim that an inode number can't be 0 in any filesystem?  I couldn't find any.

Comment: So your quote exactly answers your question, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but i am not into production, and am looking for answers for pure academic purposes only ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Usually, the inode 0 is reserved because a return value of 0 usually signals an error. Multiple method in the Linux kernel -- especially in the VFS layer shared by all file systems -- return an ino_t, e.g. [find_inode_number](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/fs/dcache.c#L2217).

There are more reserved inode numbers. For example in [ext2](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/include/linux/ext2_fs.h#L61):

```
#define EXT2_BAD_INO             1      /* Bad blocks inode */
#define EXT2_ROOT_INO            2      /* Root inode */
#define EXT2_BOOT_LOADER_INO     5      /* Boot loader inode */
#define EXT2_UNDEL_DIR_INO       6      /* Undelete directory inode */
```

and [ext3](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/include/linux/ext3_fs.h#L96) has:

```
#define EXT3_BAD_INO             1      /* Bad blocks inode */
#define EXT3_ROOT_INO            2      /* Root inode */
#define EXT3_BOOT_LOADER_INO     5      /* Boot loader inode */
#define EXT3_UNDEL_DIR_INO       6      /* Undelete directory inode */
#define EXT3_RESIZE_INO          7      /* Reserved group descriptors inode */
#define EXT3_JOURNAL_INO         8      /* Journal inode */
```

and [ext4](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L212) has:

```
#define EXT4_BAD_INO             1      /* Bad blocks inode */
#define EXT4_ROOT_INO            2      /* Root inode */
#define EXT4_USR_QUOTA_INO       3      /* User quota inode */
#define EXT4_GRP_QUOTA_INO       4      /* Group quota inode */
#define EXT4_BOOT_LOADER_INO     5      /* Boot loader inode */
#define EXT4_UNDEL_DIR_INO       6      /* Undelete directory inode */
#define EXT4_RESIZE_INO          7      /* Reserved group descriptors inode */
#define EXT4_JOURNAL_INO         8      /* Journal inode */
```

Other fileystems use the ino 1 as root inode number. In general, a file system is free to choose its inode numbers and its reserved ino values (with the exception of 0).

Comment: Also see macro `EXT2_FIRST_INO()` - it's not actually a constant.

Answer (score 36):

0 is used as a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to indicate null or no inode. similar to how pointers can be NULL in C. without a sentinel, you'd need an extra bit to test if an inode in a struct was set or not.

more info here:

> All block and inode addresses start at
>   1. The first block on the disk is block 1. 0 is used to indicate no
>   block. (Sparse files can have these
>   inside them)

http://uranus.chrysocome.net/explore2fs/es2fs.htm

for instance, in old filesystems where directories were represented as a fixed array of file entries, deleting a file would result in setting that entry's inode val to 0. when traversing the directory, any entry with an inode of 0 would be ignored.

Comment: It seems inode 1 is also reserved along with inode 0 for some special purposes.

Comment: That seems specific to ext2fs.  Your question is about filesystems in general.

Comment: @Alok: a family of unix fs's share the inode concept. none recognize 0 by convention.

Comment: Except NTFS: $MFT is inode 0, causing it not to show up in the directory listing even though it is physically present in the root directory.

Answer (score 5):

OSX specifies that inode 0 signifies a deleted file that has not yet been deleted; this may have also been used in other filesystems, as OSX is BSD-derived, although at least NetBSD seems to have now removed this usage.

See the OSX manpage for getdirentries http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getdirentries.2.html

Comment: Reading that OSX man page--I think it indicates a no-longer-valid *directory entry*.  An actual file should never change its inode number as long as it exists.  E.g. even if it's unlinked so it can't be looked up anywhere, if you still hold it open, and stat it, its inode number will still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a filesystem ages ago, I used inode 0 for the `.badblocks` pseudo-file.

On some filesystems `.badblocks` is actually present in the root directory as a regular file owned by root and mode 0. root can open it but reading or writing it is undefined.

There is some ancient tradition that inodes start from 1, #1 is `.badblocks`, and #2 is the root directory. Even though `.badblocks` is not particularly well-guaranteed, many filesystems go out of their way to make root #2.