# Why is root directory always stored in inode two?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm learning about Linux filesystems, with these sources:

```
http://linuxgazette.net/issue21/ext2.html
http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/cs40/analyze-ext2.htm
```

But I have one question about the root directory: why is its inode number always **two**? Why not one, or another number?

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule.Inode number assignment is filesystem specific.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099121/why-do-inode-numbers-start-from-1-and-not-0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first inode number is 1.  0 is used as a NULL value, to indicate that there is no inode.  Inode 1 is used to keep track of any bad blocks on the disk; it is essentially a hidden file containing the bad blocks, so that they will not be used by another file.  The bad blocks can be recorded using [`e2fsck -c`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e2fsck.8.html).  The filesystem root directory is inode 2.

The meaning of particular inode numbers differs by filesystem.  For ext4 you can find more information on the Ext4 Wiki [Ext4 Disk Layout page](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout); in particular see the "[Special inodes](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes)" table.