# Portability inode number 0 as a sentinel

Tags: c, unix, posix

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099151/1084774
to [Why do inode numbers start from 1 and not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099121/why-do-inode-numbers-start-from-1-and-not-0) states that inode number 0 is usable as a sentinel.

How portable is this usage, practically speaking?

Comment: @DavidRanieri I don't think POSIX guarantees that inode 0 is unassigned to a file. But I just did a recursive / scan on Linux, Cygwin, MacOS, and FreeBSD, and it reports no file/directory with inode 0, so tentatively, it's looking to be quite portable (I realize such scans aren't theoretically a 100% guarantee such a file can't ever be created on those systems, but I think I'll have faith ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### POSIX:

POSIX doesn't make any guarantees about inode numbers, so they can be zero and still be POSIX-compliant.

However, inode numbers can be very big, and specifically 4294967296 = 0x100000000 - namely 0 when truncated to 32 bits.

For this case, [POSIX provides `EOVERFLOW`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html):

> [...] the file serial number cannot be represented correctly in the structure pointed to by buf.

### Linux:

Linux has [this function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.10/source/include/linux/fs.h#L3072):

```
/*
 * Userspace may rely on the the inode number being non-zero. For example, glibc
 * simply ignores files with zero i_ino in unlink() and other places.
 *
 * As an additional complication, if userspace was compiled with
 * _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=32 on a 64-bit kernel we'll only end up reading out the
 * lower 32 bits, so we need to check that those aren't zero explicitly. With
 * _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64, this may cause some harmless false-negatives, but
 * better safe than sorry.
 */
static inline bool is_zero_ino(ino_t ino)
{
    return (u32)ino == 0;
}
```

However, it is currently used only by tmpfs. The Linux kernel filesystem doesn't dictate to filesystems whether or not inode 0 is allowed, but in practice, they all avoid inode number 0, and you will find that some of them actually do [use inode 0 as a sentinel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.10/source/fs/xfs/xfs_icache.c#L1402).

### FreeBSD:

FreeBSD uses -1 ([VNOVAL](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/vnode.h?v=FREEBSD-12-STABLE#L369)) as a sentinel, and does not dictate to filesystems whether or not they can use inode 0.

However, from surveying the filesystems supported by FreeBSD, they don't use inode 0.

### MacOS:

As [another answer on the linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126663/10678955) says:

> OSX specifies that inode 0 signifies a deleted file that has not yet been deleted;

### NTFS:

Inode 0 is [reserved for the MFT](http://inform.pucp.edu.pe/%7Einf232/Ntfs/ntfs_doc_v0.5/files/mft.html). MFT is not visible to users.

However, if your code is going to be used by the NTFS tools (mkfs, ntfsinfo, etc.) e.g. with [NTFS-3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G), then you can't assume that inode 0 doesn't exist.

### Other major OSes and filesystems:

For a filesystem designer, allowing inode 0 to be a regular inode is just a headache. So it stands to reason that they will practically avoid it.

It's useful to treat it in a special way, but not necessarily as a sentinel. In filesystems where inode numbers are computed from on-disk offsets, it might be useful to have inode 0, but have it be internal.

### Minor OSes and filesystems:

Writing filesystems is actually not very difficult these days, and a lot of people write toy filesystems, or real filesystems for environments like microcontrollers or other embedded environments.

There the variation could be much greater, and you shouldn't make any non-POSIX assumptions.

An example even exists [in the linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365520/10678955).

### The future:

While not likely, it is possible that the a future POSIX standard could codify inode 0 for some purpose, but not necessarily as a sentinel.

### Conclusion:

Assuming inode 0 is not practically portable in the general sense, but it is practically portable across Linux and FreeBSD.

Comment: Thank you. That's a very well-written answer!